# react cookie consent not registering on first site visit

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, gatsby

I have a react gatsby site and I'm using the gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies plugin.

This is in my gatsby-config:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies",
  options: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      trackingId: "", // Google Analytics Property ID
      cookieName: "", // Cookie name
      anonymize: true, // Anonymize IP addresses (required by German privacy law)
      allowAdFeatures: false, // Collect user information for ad reports (audience demographics, interests)
    },
    environments: ["production", "development"],
  },
},
```

The consent banner comes up properly and when I hit accept, it can register that through the onAcccept parameter which makes me feel I have the consent banner set up properly. However, no data is sent to google analytics until the user goes to a new page. Once the new user goes to a new page, then both the page of site entry and the new page is registered.

I have the latest version of the plugin (v2.0.8) and from gatsby's docs "Reloading the page after setting the cookies is not required anymore". I know that I can use the intializeAndTrack function on accept, but would love to not have to do that.

And here is my cookie consent component:

```
  <CookieConsent
    // debug
    // enableDeclineButton
    disableStyles
    location="bottom"
    buttonClasses="cc-button"
    buttonWrapperClasses="cc-button-wrap"
    declineButtonClasses="cc-button-no"
    containerClasses="cc-container"
    contentClasses="cc-content"
    buttonText="Accept"
    ariaAcceptLabel="Accept"
    declineButtonText="Reject"
    ariaDeclineLabel="Reject"
    cookieName="gil-gdpr-google-analytics"
  >
    We use cookies to enhance site navigation, analyze site usage, and
    support our marketing efforts. By accepting cookies, you are allowing
    them to be stored on your device.
  </CookieConsent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reloading the page after setting the cookies is not required anymore

This means that you don't need to refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to start the tracking because it's fired in the `onClientUpdate` event, so, when the user access a new page and Gatsby catches the event, within the scope of the React routing. However, to start tracking once the user accepts the GDPR, you need to initialize the `initializeAndTrack` as the name and the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/#initialize-and-track) suggest:

> This gatsby plugin now supports initializing and tracking right after
> a user accepts the cookie consent.

```
// in your cookie banner

import { useLocation } from "@reach/router" // this helps tracking the location
import { initializeAndTrack } from 'gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies'
```

> Then you can execute `initializeAndTrack(location)` in your cookie
> banner callback. This will initialize the plugin with your options
> from the `gatsby-config.js` and then starts tracking the user based on
> the cookies/services are accepted.

What you were describing is the intended behavior, because, without the `initializeAndTrack` event, the first trigger of the GPRD tracking is on the first user navigation (`onClientUpdate`).

Comment: ahhhh I see. The way I read the docs I thought the most recent update made it so you didn't need the initializeAndTrack(). That makes sense though, thank you!